# Hot to get a `didInsertElement` like behaviour for the `{{#each}}` helper without specifying `itemViewClass`?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a Ember Component with a `{{#each}}` helper. I use didInsertElement on the Component to work with the DOM using jQuery.

It seems like the `{{each}}` helper generates something like a view for each iteration. I think its not a *real* view since there is no tag in the DOM representing the View.

When the array bound to the `{{#each}}` helper changes, the complete `{{#each}}` seems to be rerendered. So I need to my work with the DOM again!

What is the best way to do this?

I *could* specify `itemViewClass` on the `{{#each}}` helper, and use the `didInsertElement` on the itemView. But that seems to be unelegant for some reasons:

- It will generate additional HTML tags for the DOM, since then I have a *real* View with a representing DOM tag for each iteration, in opposite to the *fake?* views used normally.
- I can not specify the itemView on the component in any way, like a property or something. I have to use a normal View directly on the Ember App, which breaks the component seperation.
- I have to split the jQuery code, and communicate over the parentView to access all Items.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just an FYI, you can eliminate the extra tag that a view generates by setting the `tagName` attribute to an empty string.

Comment: @GJK Thanks! maybe then I could build something like the `{{#each}}` helper with components and then have a action `allRerendered`. Still notthe most elegant solution I think.